# Cannot match route in Angular

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

I need help with routing.
I had a primary router and a aux router.
I want to navigate to both routes my config is

```
path: 'kunden',
    children: [
      { path: 'detail/:id', component: KundenDetailComponent },
      { path: 'list', component: KundenListComponent, outlet: 'sidebar' }
    ]
```

and the route is

```
<a [routerLink]="['../kunden/detail/1',{ outlets: { sidebar: ['kunden', 'list']}}]">Sidebar</a>
```

but i get an error

```
cannot match any route for /kunden/detail/1(sidebar:kunden/list) for kunden/detail/1
```

Comment: Maybe it will help you: [url](https://onehungrymind.com/named-router-outlets-in-angular-2/)

Comment: Can you try `<a [routerLink]="['/kunden', 'detail', '1']>Sidebar</a>` ?